# Max returns a wrong answer

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the following script

```
def fun(s):

    lst = [] 
    for i in range (len(s)):
        for j in range(i , len(s)):
            if not s[i:j] :
                pass
            elif len(s[i:j]) == len(set(s[i:j])):
                lst.append(s[i:j])

    print (lst )
    print (max(lst))


s = 'abcabcbb' 
fun(s)
```

The goal is to find the longest substring without repeating characters

when you run the script you get the output `cb` which is not the right answer

`lst` has the following elements
`['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'bca', 'c', 'ca', 'cab', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c', 'cb', 'b']` 
why does `max()` return `cb` instead of `bca`, `abc`, `cab`

if max is referring to the index then the result should be `b`

if max is referring to the length of the element then the result should be one of these `bca`, `abc`, `cab`

Comment: @alex  i think this is a completely different question

Comment: You're asking why `max()` returns `cb` instead of e.g. `abc`. It performs a letter by letter comparison. `c` is a `99` in ASCII and `a` is a `97` so `c` > `a` so `cb` > `abc`. Only if it was the same letter being compared, the comparison would go on. It is called lexicographical ordering.